# How to insert EEG triggers from one PsychoPy script into another?

Tags: python, psychopy

I am working on adding EEG triggers to this script in PsychoPy I wrote through builder mode in PsychoPy, as I am new to coding. The experiment is a series of audio recordings of sentence stems and visual word endings – the recordings and words are called up through a spreadsheet. We are interested in participants’ responses upon viewing the word endings.

Below is my current script without the EEG triggers, and beneath it is a script from someone else with the same system they have used to insert EEG triggers. I am looking to record beginning at the end of the “Sentences” stimulus, including when during “target” and “response," and ending after they make their response.

Thank you very much for any help!

### **Here is the script I already have:**

```
------Prepare to start Routine “trial1”-------

t = 0

trial1Clock.reset()  # clock

frameN = -1

continueRoutine = True

**# update component parameters for each repeat**

target.setColor([1.000,1.000,1.000], colorSpace='rgb')

target.setText(word)

response = event.BuilderKeyResponse()

Sentences.setSound(sounds, secs=6)

**# keep track of which components have finished**

trial1Components = [target, response, Sentences, text_2]

for thisComponent in trial1Components:

if hasattr(thisComponent, 'status'):

    thisComponent.status = NOT_STARTED
```

### **And here is the code to insert EEG triggers I am trying to integrate:**

```
# Send event marker to NetStation
if mode=='eeg' and stage=='expt':
    code = 'item'
    ns.sync()
    ns.send_event(code, label='item', timestamp=egi.ms_localtime(), table = { 'item' : curr_item })
```

Answer (score 1):

You say that you "wrote the code using Builder". Did you change the code after Builder? If not, then it's always best to work from Builder itself to allow you to change other aspects of the experiment while keeping your triggers. Assuming that you can work in Builder:

If you send triggers via the parallel port, there's a component for that under I/O --> Parallel port.

Otherwise, you can insert a Code Component to run your code at the desired times:

1. In the "begin experiment" tab, add `import xxxx as ns` or however you created the `ns` object.
2. In the "begin routine" tab, add your trigger code to mark stimulus onset.
3. To mark stimulus offset, go to "each frame" tab and either (a) listen for the stimulus status like `if stim.status == FINISHED:` or (b) send the trigger at the predicted offset setting `trigger_sent = False` at "begin routine and then `if t > 2 and not trigger_sent:` (if your stimulus is 2 secs long)